# I want to stop wpa_supplicant on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wpa-supplicant

I want to stop `wpa_supplicant` on `ubuntu 14.04`.

I did follow but the `wpa_supplicant` restarted by someone.

```
$ ps aux | grep wpa

root      4947  0.0  0.0  30628  4968 ?        Ss   09:41   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant

$ sudo kill 4947

$ ps aux | grep wpa

root      5458  0.0  0.0  30628  4996 ?        Ss   09:55   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -B -P /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.pid -u -s -O /var/run/wpa_supplicant
```

I want to know who restart the supplicant and stop `wpa_supplicant` abidingly. Because I am trying to test another version `wpa_supplicant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute-force way is to break `wpa_supplicant` by renaming it. Whatever tries to start it won't find it anymore.

```
$ which wpa_supplicant 
/sbin/wpa_supplicant

$ sudo mv /sbin/wpa_supplicant /sbin/wpa_supplicant_org

$ sudo killall wpa_supplicant
```

And I got a result I wanted that the wpa_supplicant cannot restart anymore.

This method has some caveats:

- An update might fix the package again.
- You can't manually start `wpa_supplicant` when you use this method.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20.04

```
systemctl stop wpa_supplicant
systemctl disable wpa_supplicant
```

The second command will stop it from automatically starting.

Answer (score 2):

The clean way to shut down **wpa_supplicant** is

```
wpa_cli terminate
```

Sometimes you need to specify the interface as in

```
wpa_cli terminate -i wlan0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pkill wpa_supplicant
```

usually does the trick for me. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: I tested command you provide me. However, the wpa_supplicant is still restarted.

Comment: could you please check if the PID of wpa_supplicant change when you kill it?

Comment: just saw you log. it seems as if there is a `service` restarting wpa_supplicant even after you kill it. Do you have network manager installed?

Answer (score 1):

wpa_supplicant provides the WPA security. Any network manager (e.g. Network Manager,netctl etc) that deals with wifi network would use wpa_supplicant. So whenever the network manager starts it would start wpa supplicant.
If you want to permanently disable it (because may be you dont use wifi or secure wifi) then you can mask it.

```
 sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
```

then stop it:

```
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service
```

NOTE:Masking basically creates a symlink to /dev/null, so even if some service tries to start it it won't start. This would disable it until you manually unmask it again.

```
sudo systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a service that was launching it.
I did a grep inside systemd config directory

```
cd /etc/systemd/system 
grep -ri wpa
```

That showed me the name of the service that is starting this.

Used the following command to stop it

```
sudo systemctl stop <service-name>
```

If you would like to permanently disable it, remove the "WantedBy" line in the service file.